# Haskell: Substitute a character with a variable name

Tags: variables, haskell

I want to execute something like my effort here:

```
hashTag :: Char
hashTag = "#"
```

So I can therefore **reference later**:
such as adding a # to a list or assigning later

```
Point::Int -> Int -> Point -> String
Point a b x
  | firstPoint(x) == a && secondPoint(x) == b = "#"
  | otherwise = "."
```

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: You can simply use `| firstPoint(x) == a && secondPoint(x) == b = hashTag`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a problem with `hashTag` that you defined it as a `Char`, but you write a *string* literal. You either should use a *character literal*, or change the type of the `hashTag` to `String`.

If we change the type to `String`, we can use:

```
hashTag :: String
hashTag = "#"
```

in that case we can use the variable we defined with:

```
Point :: Int -> Int -> Point -> String
Point a b x
  | firstPoint x == a && secondPoint x == b = hashTag
  | otherwise = "."
```

If you define `hashTag` as a `Char`:

```
hashTag :: Char
hashTag = '#'
```

then you need to wrap it in a list to generate a `String` with a single character: `hashTag`:

```
Point :: Int -> Int -> Point -> String
Point a b x
  | firstPoint x == a && secondPoint x == b = [hashTag]
  | otherwise = "."
```